# google cloud. upsert large csv file by chunks start to take a lot longer than expected

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-run

I have a large csv files of prices that I want to upsert to a postgres table. I am reading it with pandas by chunks then uploading it into a temp table, then copy the temp table into the prices table and finally dropping the temp table. Locally this is really fast. each chunk takes 18s, and the file of 18M rows takes 14 minutes. In the google cloud run however, the first 3 chunks take 17s, the 4th one take 42s, the 5th takes 102s and after that the chunks take btween 100 and 120s (sometimes more).

my cloud run has 2 CPUs, Concurrency 200, 1GB of RAM with CPU is only allocated during request processing. My SQL isntance has 1CPU and 628 MB of Memory.

Here is the upsert code:

```
import time

import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool
from aldjemy.core import get_engine
import uuid
from typing import List

import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa


engine = get_engine(connect_args={'connect_timeout': 3600, 'pool_size': NullPool})
i = 0
with pd.read_csv("prices.csv", chunksize=350000) as reader:
    for prices in reader:
        time.sleep(0.01)
        i=i+1
        print("chunk number %s" %str(i))
        
        t = time.time()
        try:
            _ = df_upsert(data_frame=prices, engine=engine, table_name=ModelPrice._meta.db_table, match_columns=['id', 'date'])
        except Exception as e:
            raise Exception(f"{self.__class__.__name__}: {str(e)}")

        elapsed = time.time() - t
        print('price data upserted. TOTAL elapsed = %d' %elapsed)
```

and `df_upsert`:

```
def df_upsert(data_frame: pd.DataFrame, table_name: str, engine: sa.engine.Engine, match_columns: List[str]=None):
    """
    Perform an "upsert" on a PostgreSQL table from a DataFrame.

    Constructs an INSERT … ON CONFLICT statement, uploads the DataFrame to a
    temporary table, and then executes the INSERT.

    Parameters
    ----------
    data_frame : pandas.DataFrame
        The DataFrame to be upserted.
    table_name : str
        The name of the target table. Note that this string value is injected
        directly into the SQL statements, so proper quoting is required for
        table names that contain spaces, etc. A schema can be specified as
        well, e.g., 'my_schema."my table"'.
    engine : sa.engine.Engine
        The SQLAlchemy Engine to use.
    match_columns : list of str, optional
        A list of the column name(s) on which to match. If omitted, the
        primary key columns of the target table will be used. Note that these
        names *are* automatically quoted in the INSERT statement, so do not
        quote them in this list, e.g., ["my column"], not ['"my column"'].
    """
    df_columns = list(data_frame.columns)
    if not match_columns:
        insp = sa.inspect(engine)
        match_columns = insp.get_pk_constraint(table_name)[
            "constrained_columns"
        ]
    temp_table_name = f"temp_{uuid.uuid4().hex[:6]}"
    columns_to_update = [col for col in df_columns if col not in match_columns]
    insert_col_list = ", ".join([f'"{col_name}"' for col_name in df_columns])
    stmt = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} ({insert_col_list})\n"
    stmt += f"SELECT {insert_col_list} FROM {temp_table_name}\n"
    match_col_list = ", ".join([f'"{col}"' for col in match_columns])
    stmt += f"ON CONFLICT ({match_col_list}) DO UPDATE SET\n"
    stmt += ", ".join(
        [f'"{col}" = EXCLUDED."{col}"' for col in columns_to_update]
    )

    with engine.begin() as conn:
        t = time.time()
        conn.exec_driver_sql(
            f"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE {temp_table_name} AS SELECT * FROM {table_name} WHERE false"
        )
        elapsed = time.time() - t
        print('TEMPORARY TABLE created. elapsed = %d' %elapsed)
        t = time.time()
        data_frame.to_sql(temp_table_name, conn, if_exists="append", index=False)
        elapsed = time.time() - t
        print('dataframe written to TEMPORARY TABLE. elapsed = %d' %elapsed)
        t = time.time()
        conn.exec_driver_sql(stmt)
        elapsed = time.time() - t
        print('TEMPORARY TABLE copied into price table. elapsed = %d' %elapsed)
        t = time.time()
        engine.execute(f'DROP TABLE "{temp_table_name}"')
        elapsed = time.time() - t
        print('TEMPORARY TABLE dropped. elapsed = %d' %elapsed)
```

I have tried:

1. Reducing the chunk size (to 100k). Smaller chunks is worse actually. Relatively each chunk becomes slower.
2. Deleting the prices table and rebuilding the index and doing an upsert with on empty table.
3. Increase RAM and CPU on cloud run
4. Use CPU always allocated on cloud run

None of them worked.
A little more details on the timing breakdown:
first 3 chunks:
Temp Table creation: 0s
Copy to Temp table: 9s
Copy from Temp table to prices table: 7-9s
Drop Temp table: 0s

Afterwards:
Temp Table creation: 0s
Copy to Temp table: 48s
Copy from Temp table to prices table: 74s
Drop Temp table: 0s

Comment: You should try the built container on your local environment with the same quantity of CPU and memory (you can constrain your docker run environment with parameters), and see if you have the same behavior

Comment: Thanks @guillaumeblaquiere, but giving it more RAM is not a solution. Even if I use a small chunksize of 10k or 5k, I get the same problem after a few hundred chunks. I know that if I increase the RAM, the issue starts appearing later (ie instead of appearing at chunk 4, it starts at chunk 20 for example). So yes, beefing up the machine works. But my file is 700MB (DB size 3.5GB), it seems inappropriate to have an 8GB machine for a such a small file of 700MB. What if the file is 1TB? we use 8TB of RAM?

Comment: Serverless has limited size of memory and it's volunteer. The current trend is to parallelize the processing with multiple small unit of processing in parallel. Your chunk model is great and works well for 1 - 2 Gb (with memory of your Cloud Functions to 8Gb or use Cloud Run with 32Gb). For larger file, 1 or 8Tb, you must change your design. Large distributed system, like dataflow or dataproc, are more suitable for this king of use cases.

Comment: yes, I understand. but my data is small. I don't understand why the processing time per chunk spikes after a few chunks. my system ressources should be enough to handle this.

Comment: Did you track the memory usage? Are you sure you don't have memory leak that increase the time chunk after chunk.

Comment: With small chunks the memory usage is fine. I dont think there is any leak. See code. Does is there an issue?

Comment: I'm not python expert. Something with your engine.Begin(). It's never close. Maybe the end of the with do that automatically, but I can't commit...